# How to get minutes on timestamp in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get a current timestamp object which is minutes l。 How do I do it with JavaScript?

Here my code ：

```
var mins = "";
var new_timestamp = parseInt($("#current_time").data("timestamp")) + 1000;
var date = new Date(new_timestamp);
for (var b = 0; b < 60; b++) {
    if (b == date.getMinutes()) {
        str += "<option selected>" + (b < 10 ? ("0" + b) : b) + "</option>";
    } else {
        str += "<option>" + (b < 10 ? ("0" + b) : b) + "</option>";
    }

}
$("#bank-order-time  [name=\"minutes\"]").html(mins);
```

HTML :

```
<select name="minutes">
```

Comment: Why do you loop 0..60, when you can simply use `data.getMinutes()`? Oh...

Comment: i did some mistake , should't be str on loop

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
```

`new Date()` gives you a Date object of then time. You don't need to input a timestamp.

And `date.getMinutes()` give you the minute as you already know.

And if you need to get the current time again, remember you need to create a new Date object and do not use the old one.

Answer (score 0):

My answer：

```
   (function(){
                 var str ="";
                 var new_timestamp =  parseInt($("#current_time").data("timestamp"))+1000;
                 var date = new Date(new_timestamp);
                for( var a = 0; a < 24 ; a++)
                {
                    if( a== date.getHours() )
                    {
                        str +="<option selected>"+(a<10?("0"+a):a)+"</option>" ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       str +="<option>"+(a<10?("0"+a):a)+"</option>" ; 
                    }

                }

                $("#bank-order-time  [name=\"hour\"]").html(str);

                 var mins = "";

                for( var b = 0; b < 60; b++)
                {
                    if( b == date.getMinutes())
                    {
                        mins +="<option selected>"+(b<10?("0"+b):b)+"</option>" ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       mins +="<option>"+(b<10?("0"+b):b)+"</option>" ; 
                    }

                }
                $("#bank-order-time  [name=\"minutes\"]").html(mins);

            })();
```